# Procedimiento almacenado de MYSQL a SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Crear un procedimiento almacenado en `SqlServer`, yo estoy acostumbrado a usar `MYSQL` pero ahora tengo que hacer un procedimiento almacenado que inserte valores pero que el id-código que auto incremente cada vez que se ingrese datos 
así seria en `MYSQL`:

```
delimiter
create procedure insert_tienda
(xnombtien varchar(50),
xobsvtien varchar(50))
begin
select count(*) into @num from tienda;
set @idtienda=concat('T',right(concat('000',cast((@num +1)as char)),4));
insert into tienda values(@idtienda,xnombtien,xobsvtien,1);
commit;
end;
```

Pero no sé como hacerlo en `SQLSERVER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El equivalente en SQL Server vendría a ser:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_tienda 
    @xnombtien varchar(50), @xobsvtien varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @num int;

SELECT @num = COUNT(*) FROM tienda

INSERT INTO tienda VALUES ('T' + right('000' + cast(@num + 1 as varchar(3)), 3)
            , @xnombtien, @xobsvtien, 1)    
END
GO
```

y para llamarlo no tendrías más que utilizar:

```
EXEC insert_tienda 'tienda1', 'observaciones tienda 1';
```

Supongo que eres consciente de que con este procedimiento almacenado:

- No puedes tener más de 999 identificadores diferentes
- Si eliminas algún registro existente obtendrás identificadores repetidos

Comment: se puede hacer que los identificadores no se repitan?

Comment: Claro que se puede. Pero la forma dependerá de los requisitos que tengas. A priori la forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es tener como clave principal un campo numérico autoincremental (como te indicaba Juan Manuel en su respuesta).
Luego en tu aplicación, cuando vayas a mostrar el código, puedes formatearlo con la T y los ceros. Pero como te comentaba depende de los requisitos que tengas. ¿Debe almacenarse el código alfanumérico en base de datos? ¿Puede haber huecos en la numeración? ...

Answer (score 0):

Basta con hacer lo siguiente:

Al crear la tabla en SQL Server, en las propiedades del campo `id-codigo` indiques en la *Especificación de Identidad* el incremento que deseas para dicho campo. Con eso consigues un campo autoincremental.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]